# after hitting delete in commit the table view didn't upgrade?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, commit

My table view is divided in two sections :
completed tasks and to do.

When I hit delete I want the to do task in the completed task and vice versa.

This is my viewDidAppear:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
```

and this my commit:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let thisTask = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TaskModel

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        thisTask.completed = true
    }
    else {
        thisTask.completed = false
    }
    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
}
```

this the controllerDidChange:

```
 func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the `tableView`'s dataSource and delegate properties are set. Other than that you could try this:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates();
}

func controllererDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
self.viewWillAppear(false)
```

Comment: Can you improve the answer by adding some explanation as to where in context to put this, and why it works?

Comment: it will be in a func called viewWillAppear and it will refresh the current view